# Prevent Button from inheriting BackColor of Parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I have a parent control which has a `BackColor` other than `SystemColors.Control`, but I have buttons on that parent control that I want to be drawn in the system them. However, when I do not change the `BackColor` of the buttons, it's drawn in the color of the parent. When I change the `BackColor` of the button to `SystemColors.Control`, it isn't drawn in the Windows theme anymore.

[image]
*The left version is with `SystemColors.Control` and the right is without changing the `BackColor`.*

[image]
*Blown up, it looks like this. Here you can see that the buttons have a solid background.*

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

The effect in the image can be accomplished by creating a new .NET 2.0 WinForms project and changing the constructor of `Form1` to the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var textBox = new TextBox();
    Controls.Add(textBox);

    var button = new Button { Text = "L", Width = 23, Height = 18, Left = -1, Top = -1 };
    textBox.Controls.Add(button);

    // Disable the line below to get the default behavior
    button.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
}
```

Comment: I can't see, resembles the normal gradient with the control color on the button face.  Make it bigger.

Comment: @Hans Passant - There you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I unforuantely only have access to Windows 7 at the moment so I can't test on XP etc. but are you calling `Application.EnableVisualStyles` in the `Main` entry point of your WinForms application?

On Windows 7 with Aero enabled the buttons do not assume the parent color if `Application.EnableVisualStyles` is called.

**NB:** You should set `button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;` and do not explicitly set the `BackColor` property of the button.

Comment: Yes. The screen shot is from Windows 7 with the Basic theme (i.e. no Aero). I've added a code sample that reproduces the effect in a new, clean WinForms project.