# Panel's paint event also paints the controls in the panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am trying to paint a panel with gradient background effect. I have 3 buttons inside the panel. The buttons also got painted. How do I paint only the panel without its child controls

```
void pnl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //Create a diagonal linear gradient with four stops.   
    LinearGradientBrush myLinearGradientBrush =
            new LinearGradientBrush(e.ClipRectangle, 
                                    Color.Red, Color.White,
                                    LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
    ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();

    Color c1 = StringToColor("FFAD5C");
    Color c2 = StringToColor("ffffff");
    Color c3 = StringToColor("FFAD5C");

    cb.Positions = new[] { 0, (float)0.75, 1 };
    cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2, c3 };
    myLinearGradientBrush.InterpolationColors = cb;
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myLinearGradientBrush, e.ClipRectangle);
}
```

Comment: Winforms support `LinearGradientBrush`???

Comment: @bash.d Why shouldn't it? After all, how can it not "support" something like this as long as it provides a canvas to draw onto?

Comment: I thought it was exclusive to WPF

Comment: Look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489663/prevent-button-from-inheriting-backcolor-of-parent

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour with your exact code (using arbitrary colors, since I don't have your `StringToColor` method)

Comment: @jhon You could use Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Gray.

Comment: @bash.d It's in the `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` namespace.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Use `ColorTranslater.FromHTML` and include the # sign in front of the string.  To the OP, avoid using `e.ClipRectangle`, just use the panel's ClientRectangle property.  As for the buttons, my guess would be you are painting the buttons with the same handler.

Comment: @Albert yes, that is exactly what I did, but the buttons do not get painted; only the panel.

Comment: This is not how painting works in Winforms, the panel's Paint event cannot paint over a button.  You could only mess this up if you use CreateGraphics.  *Never* use that, call the panel's Invalidate() method to get it to repaint itself.

Comment: @john, Now I have used pnl.ClientRectangle instead of using e.ClipRectangle and it works fine. Thanks Jhon